# Alphabetizing Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

So I'm having a couple of troubles with my code. For starters, I have this problem which is outputting all of the arrays. Mind you I have only been coding for 12 days and my teacher has somewhat skipped over the very basics in C# coding due to my college's outlook on learning. AND I just learned that it doesn't order them alphabetically.....

```
    static int inputPartInformation(string[] pl)
    {
        int i = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a Name: ");
            //for the player
            pl[i] = Console.ReadLine();

        }
        while (pl[i++].CompareTo("Q") != 0);
        //if they write Q for the player it will quit
        return i - 1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] players = new String[100];
        Array.Sort(players);
        // Sort array.

        //defines players in this new instance

        var count = inputPartInformation(players);

        //for the portion of the code that handles the input

        //calculates the average score

        Console.WriteLine("List of People in Order: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6},", players);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You might want to debug the code line by line to see what's happening! :)

Comment: Well the problem is, is that Array.Sort isn't working and I had to write {0}, {1}, for each of the entered Names, even though I don't know the number of people they are going to enter :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You are sorting before the names are populated; that does nothing.
- You are printing a single item using a fixed multi-item list of parameter references `{0}, {1},{2}` and so on; it is not going to work, and even if it did it would limit your output to the first seven items
- You do not know how many items to sort. Change `void inputPartInformation(string[] pl)` to return `count` (which is `i-1`), and use `Array.Sort(players, 0, count);`

The simplest way to convert multiple strings into a single string is by using `string.Join`:

```
Console.WriteLine("List of People in Order: {0}", string.Join(", ", players.Take(count)));
```

Comment: There we go! Put the sort after the var count. I added in the return i-1 earlier but for some reason posted an earlier revision of the code. Everything is working right! :D

Answer (score 1):

First, "Q" is being added to the input list because you don't test for "Q"  until *after* the input has been accepted and inserted into your array. One way of reworking this would be to hold the input name into a temporary variable, test *that* for "Q", and add it to your array only if it is something else. Within your loop, modify your input/test to something like:

```
   bool enteringNames=true;
   do{
    String nextName = Console.ReadLine();
    if (nextName.CompareTo("Q")==0)
    {
       enteringNames=false;
    }
    else
    {
       p[i]=nextName;
    }
    i++;
  }
  while(enteringNames);
```

This is just one way of getting the job done. Keep in mind that a fixed 100-entry array isn't the most robust way of doing this...never know how many names might be going in!

Now, the last WriteLine is a bit odd, but I think you can figure that part out on your own - its pretty straightforward to either iterate through the array, or just join all the strings together :)

Second, your sort isn't working because you call Array.Sort(players) *before* you call inputPartInformation(players) to actually load the data - so you're sorting without any data!. Move the Array.Sort call after the call to inputPartInformation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work, but first try to study about the APIs

```
static int inputPartInformation(string[] pl)
    {

        int i = 0;
        String temp;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a Name: ");
            temp=Console.ReadLine();
            if (temp=="Q")
                break;
            else pl[i++] = temp;
        }
        return i;

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        String[] players = new String[100];

        int size=inputPartInformation(players);

        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(players[i]);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q is appearing in your outcome because you are assigning it to your array.

Rewrite you function to check the value before you assign it, for example

```
static void inputPartInformation(string[] pl)
    {
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a Name: ");
            //for the player
            newStrInput = Console.ReadLine();

if (newStrInput == "Q")
break;//if they write Q for the player it will quit

pl[i]=newStrInput;
i++;
     }
        while (i>-1);//infinite loop        

    }
```